# Retornar o valor que for clicado de um array em uma function. Só sei fazer usando event.target

Tags: javascript, funções, dom

Quero retornar o valor que for clicado, do array. Sei fazer isso apenas com add.Eventlistener. No caso e.target.

```
<h2 onclick="menuclick()" class="notselectable btnmenu">a</h2>
<h2 onclick="menuclick()" class="notselectable btnmenu">b</h2>
<h2 onclick="menuclick()" class="notselectable btnmenu">c</h2>
<h2 onclick="menuclick()" class="notselectable btnmenu">d</h2>



function menuclick() {
    const btnmenu = document.getElementsByClassName('btnmenu');
    Array.from(btnmenu).forEach(function (item) {
        console.log(target);

    })
}
item is not defined;
(Quero que retorne 'a' se clicado no 'a'. wtc)
```

Comment: Pensei em  colocar onload em vez de on click no html, e colocar um event addEventListener('click') dentro da função. Nao sei se está errado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isso é muito simples. Dois passos:

- se passares o `this` dentro de `onclick="menuclick()"` tens o elemento que clicaste.
- depois basta extrair o texto com (por exemplo) `.textContent`

```js
function menuclick(h2) {
  const texto = h2.textContent;
  console.log(texto);
}
```

```html
<h2 onclick="menuclick(this)" class="notselectable btnmenu">a</h2>
<h2 onclick="menuclick(this)" class="notselectable btnmenu">b</h2>
<h2 onclick="menuclick(this)" class="notselectable btnmenu">c</h2>
<h2 onclick="menuclick(this)" class="notselectable btnmenu">d</h2>
```